# HPE SSA: After completing the configuration - reboot the system

Tags: hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, ilo, hpe

From the HPE ProLiant System Utilities (BIOS) I booted into HPE Smart Storage Administrator (SSA) to migrate a logical drive with RAID6 (and existing data) to RAID5. After starting the migration task, which would need several hours to complete, the only thing I could do was clicking on `X` in the top right corner. After that I was stuck on a screen saying:

> After completing the configuration - reboot the system.

What does that mean? Can I reboot the server through iLO (either *Reset* or *Cold boot*) or do I have to wait until the migration completes to finally boot into my OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry to reboot your server e. g. by selecting *Reset* on iLO. The migration will happen automatically in the background.

I was able to use the storage immediately again after I booted into the OS. The data was still *and* already available while the migration was still occuring.